# Can't run TestNG with custom class name from command line with Maven

Tags: java, selenium, maven, intellij-idea, testng

I'm using the Selenium plugin with Maven and TestNG on Intellij IDEA. I'm trying to run my projects from the command line using "mvn clean test". This command works fine when I make a new project which comes with "MainPageTest.java" as it's test class. When I change the class/file name to "Runner.java" or anything else I can run it from the IDE but not from the command line.
This is the thread when it works.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ demo ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\demo\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\demo\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\demo\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\demo\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\demo\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ demo ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.example.demo.MainPageTest

// WebDriver related stuff

[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  17.200 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-16T22:42:10-05:00
[INFO] --------------------------------------
```

This is when I change the name of the class:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ demo ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\demo\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\demo\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\demo\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\demo\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\demo\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ demo ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.076 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-16T22:47:44-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, there are no errors, but it doesn't run the test. I've tried rebuilding the project, running mvn clean install, and adding a testng.xml file but nothing works and there's no mention of MainPageTest anywhere else in the project / config. Someone please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, all I did was specify my testng.xml in my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="All Test Suite">
    <test verbose="2" preserve-order="true" name="C:/Users/Admin/IdeaProjects/demo">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.demo.Runner">
                <methods>
                    <include name="test1"/>
                    <include name="test2"/>
                    <include name="test3"/>
                    <include name="test4"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.22.2</version>
<configuration>
    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>              
    <suiteXmlFiles>
        <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
```